# Is it possible to install specific npm libary through gulp script?

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install, npm-scripts, gulp-install

I see there is a "gulp-install" library with which we can install all libraries which are mentioned in package.json. Something like this.

var install = require("gulp-install");

gulp.src(['./package.json'])
  .pipe(install());

But I couldn't find a way to install a specific library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `child_process.exec` function to execute shell commands, like `npm install`, for example. Here is the documentation for that: https://nodejs.org/docs/v8.9.4/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback